# a "single frame" of archival footage

Tags: meaning

what does "[single frame](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/shoah)" mean in "director Claude Lanzmann spent 11 years on this sprawling documentary about the Holocaust, conducting his own interviews and refusing to use a single frame of archival footage"? Does it mean a still frame, which is a single static image taken from a film or video, which are moving images? Thank you!

Comment: It wouldn't be idiomatic without the implied negation of ***refusing***. But *[not] **a single frame of*** is just an exaggeratedly emphatic alternative to *[not] **any*** (the amount of archival footage he used was ***none whatsoever***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean he refused to use a a particular still frame from some archive footage. It means that he refused to use any footage at all, still or moving.

Refusing to use a 'a single *part of X*' where X is something that may be divided into parts, means (strongly) refusing to use *any of X at all*.

I will not repeat a single word of what John said (I will not repeat *any* of what John said).

There is not a single crumb of cake left (the cake is all gone).

There was not a single person there who disagreed with me (everyone agreed with me)

Not a single passenger was left alive after the plane crashed (all the passengers died in the plane crash).

> not a single
>
> phrase
>
> not even one
>
> *You didn’t write a single letter the whole time you were away.*

[Not a single (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-a-single#:%7E:text=DEFINITIONS1,Nothing%2C%20none%20and%20no%20one)

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!